# unexpected ng-ui-bootstrap typeahead behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

**Tl;dr:** When flipping a boolean to false that is bound to an ng-if attribute, the element with the ng-if attribute remains in the DOM until exactly three other elements are selected. Why is the element not disappearing immediately once the boolean is flipped to false?

I've got a typeahead setup with a typeahead-no-results boolean attached to a warning message, that looks like this

```
<input class="full-width" id="customerParentInput" 
       ng-model="$ctrl.customer.customerParentId"
       uib-typeahead="option.value as option.key for option in $ctrl.customerLookupData.data | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10"
       typeahead-no-results="$ctrl.noResultParent"/>
<label ng-if="$ctrl.noResultParent" class="text-danger">No results. Create new customers in the Customer page in the Settings tab.</label>
```

I think it is a known issue with the typeahead that when you have 0 results, and you empty the text box, the boolean will not flip back to false. So with an empty text box my label still appears in the DOM.

So I set up a event listener that waits for the input to lose focus. Once it does lose focus it looks to see if the boolean is still true, and if the text box has any value in it.

Here's that code.

```
setListener = () => {
    $('#customerParentInput').blur(() => {
        var inputVal: string = $('#customerParentInput').val();
        if (this.noResultParent === true && inputVal.length === 0) {
            this.noResultParent = false;
        }
    });
};
```

So this forces the boolean my label is attached to to equal false. So in theory this should make the label go away.

Here is the problem. The label will stay visible in the DOM until I click on exactly three other elements in the DOM.

So for example,

I type in the text box

No results are found, I'll shift focus, the warning remains, makes sense.

I go back, remove all text, lose focus.

My listener fires off, the boolean is set to false, but the label remains.

I click on three different input boxes, and then my label will disappear.

Does anyone know why this is a necessary part of making my label go away? And is there anything I can do to make the label vanish immediately once the boolean is flipped to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for fixing the label shown when the input text is empty, maybe this could be better:

```
<label ng-if="$ctrl.noResultParent && $ctrl.customer.customerParentId.length > 0" class="text-danger">No results. Create new customers in the Customer page in the Settings tab.</label>
```

and maybe also the other issue may be fixed

Comment: Words cannot express how dumb I feel, haha. Obviously I should have been including the second condition in the ng-if statement, not trying to strong arm the first one to fit my needs. Thank you so much, I just implemented your recommendation and it worked like a charm! I must have had crazy tunnel vision to have not seen this as the solution.

Comment: You are welcome :) it happens, sometimes the best solution are the simplest ones  :D